# JAXB POJO's generated from WDSL seem cumbersome to use

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I'm not new to SOAP and turning WSDL's into POJO's. I've managed to connect to the web service and retrieve the data I need.

The problem rests in traversing the object hierarchy that the WSDL created. 
Most of the variables stored in the generated classes are of the type `JAXBElement<NameOfJavaClassHere>`. So when ever I want that object I need to issue a call like `ListOfEntitiesType loe = ents.getListOfEntities().getValue();` The `.getValue()` is where I have my issue.

Does there exist a way of making this a smoother integration? If I have to keep doing a `getValue()` it's going to be a death of 1000 cuts.

It feels like they left in a level of indirection at the client level that they didn't need to.

I've tried to unmarshal the xml with a `JAXBContent` object, there are a lot of examples on the net on how to do this, but it didn't work in this case. My object came out as null.

Should the WSDL not make POJO's that don't need all this casting about with generics?

Did I use the wrong settings on my `wsimport` command that came with java 1.7?

Should I use a different wsimport-ish program altogether to generate my POJO's?

If I have to stick with the `.getValue()` thing, I think I'd much rather make an xpath interface to the raw XML or turn the whole thing into Hashtables and ArrayLists than deal with this.

At least then, I'd have direct access to the info I want.

Comment: Excessive occurrence of JAXBElement isn't the usual case. But we'd have to see the XML schema used for defining the payload to assess where the problem comes in.

Comment: The WSDL is located here... https://gw.sam.gov/SAMWS/1.0/Entity?wsdl It's a site where companies go to register to do business with the federal government.

Comment: Interesting XML Schema, but definitely a blow for JAXB users. See my analysis.

Comment: Added a sentence - retain minOccurs="0".

Comment: Thank you both. I'm going to try out each solution and see how things pan out... I really wish I could select both answers as accepted as they are both thorough and well thought out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [XML schema](http://gw.sam.gov/SAMWS/1.0/Entity?wsd) has probably been developed under the influence of some bureaucratic rule. Consider, e.g.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DUNSNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

which results in a field

```
protected JAXBElement<String> dunsNumber;
```

causing the highly circumstantial get and set procedure you have (rightly) complained about. - What does the XML Schema entry mean? It says the element is a string, can be omitted and it must be possible to distinguish between an empty string and an absent string *even when the element is present*.

Here is a little experiment:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       version="1.0">
<xs:element name="root" type="RootType"/>
<xs:complexType name="RootType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="elem"  type="ElemType"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ElemType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="str01"    type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="str1"     type="xs:string"/>
    <!-- The following element compiles to a JAXBElement<String> -->
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="str01nil" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="str1nil"  nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <elem>
    <str01></str01>
    <str1></str1>
    <str01nil></str01nil>
    <str1nil></str1nil>
  </elem>
  <elem>
    <str1>must be there</str1>
    <str01nil xsi:nil="true"></str01nil>
    <str1nil>must be there</str1nil>
  </elem>
</root>
```

And here is what is printed by an unmarshalling routine:

```
str01    []
str1     []
str01Nil []
str1Nil  []
str01    [null]
str1     [must be there]
str01Nil [null]
str1Nil  [must be there]
```

What happens if you omit `<str01nil xsi:nil="true"></str01nil>` completely? The outcome will be the same, method `JAXBElement.getValue()` will return null, and that's it.

Now (sorry for the length of the answer) we can discuss what you can do to return to "sane" Java code generated from the XML schema. I would simply remove nillable="true" and use the resulting code. If you marshal, a null in a field will not produce an element. On unmarshal, there's the weak chance that you see an empty element with an xsi:nil="true". (It is essential to retain minOccurs="0", though.)

Comment: I ended up removing the occurrences of nillable="true" out of the wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few use cases where a `JAXBElement` is required to be able to round trip XML as defined in the XML Schema.  If you are seeing alot of `JAXBElement` in your generated model then several of these conditions are probably true.

1. An element is both `nillable="true"` and `minOccurs="0"`.  In this case what does `null` on the mapped field/property mean?  When the property is `JAXBElement` a null value means the element isn't present and a `JAXBElement` wrapping null means an XML element with `xsi:nil="true"`.
2. There are 2 global elements with the same named complex type.  Since in JAXB classes correspond to complex types a way is needed to capture which root element was encountered.

   - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html
3. There is a choice structure where either `foo` or `bar` elements can occur and they are the same type.  Here a `JAXBElement` is required because simply encountering a `String` value isn't enough to indicate which element should be marshalled.
4. An element with `xsi:nil` is encountered in the document that contains attributes.  In this example the object corresponding to that element can still be unmarshalled to hold the attribute values, but JAXBElement can stil indicate that the element was null.

**Mechanisms to Reduce the Number of `JAXBElement` in the Model**

- Binding file with `generateElementProperty` set to false.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.1">
      <globalBindings>
          <generateElementProperty>false</generateElementProperty>
      </globalBindings>
  </bindings>
  ```
- Simple plugin for XJC - https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#simple

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.1">
      <globalBindings>
          <xjc:simple />
      </globalBindings>
  </bindings>
  ```

Comment: Viewing the wdsl here... https://gw.sam.gov/SAMWS/1.0/Entity?wsdl  it appears that nearly all the elements that contain data that a developer would be interested in have both nillable="true" and minOccurs="0". What would Happen if I just stripped those strings out of the WSDL and create my objects then?

Comment: @BryanJames - I have updated my answer with a couple of binding files that may eliminate the need for you to modify the XML Schema.

Comment: How would one go about testing your <globalBindings> solution if all they have is a WSDL and wsimport?  Where would we *attach* this XML to and how?